# Terraform file to create multiple s3 buckets in multiple regions using loops and I want to attach custom bucket policies according to region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform file to create multiple s3 buckets in multiple regions using loops and I want to attach custom bucket policies according to region.

I am able to create buckets by using below code but the policies are not getting attached.

```
variable "bucket_prefix" {
  default = "sankethcl1234"
}

# Create S3 buckets in us-east-1
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

# Create S3 buckets in us-west-1
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-west-1"
  region = "us-west-1"
}

# Create 2 S3 buckets in us-east-1
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1" {
  count    = 2
  provider = aws.us-east-1
  bucket   = "${var.bucket_prefix}-us-east-1-${count.index + 1}"
  acl      = "private"
}

# Define a bucket policy for S3 buckets in us-east-1
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1" {
  count  = 2
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_east_1[count.index].id
  policy = templatefile("${path.module}/bucket_policy_east.json", { bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_east_1[count.index].id })
}

# Create 2 S3 buckets in us-west-1
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1" {
  count    = 2
  provider = aws.us-west-1
  bucket   = "${var.bucket_prefix}-us-west-1-${count.index + 1}"
}

# Define a bucket policy for S3 buckets in us-west-1
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1" {
  count  = 2
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_west_1[count.index].id
  policy = templatefile("${path.module}/bucket_policy_west.json", { bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_west_1[count.index].id })
}
```

Please help me to upload the policies getting below error

> Error: putting S3 Bucket (sankethcl1234-us-east-1-2) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 301, RequestID: DNG0HE3RABQTZNJ6, HostID: mmJps0saH/1+HskYQPtwXG71ofDOUSXm95JKy4dZY5IpDpI5xuFFO3L1jU+NuyMJ49THk5rPkUs=, api error PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.with aws_s3_bucket_policy.sankethcl1234_us_east_1[1],
> on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1":
> 49: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1" {

> Error: putting S3 Bucket (sankethcl1234-us-east-1-1) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 301, RequestID: DNG5Z9NBPMXZAHEH, HostID: TVe1g0aYuuDF/6cT/KC/iGJOmwnDvsLdjkRhte6AwpHdqzewWsV/MUVed+B/Z0wohPXTnOlLp8I=, api error PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.with aws_s3_bucket_policy.sankethcl1234_us_east_1[0],
> on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1":
> 49: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1" {

> Error: putting S3 Bucket (sankethcl1234-us-west-1-2) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 301, RequestID: G4B8RZYRDH20298A, HostID: bDgPRXI49MSxEdesSpIBueXVnvV1LHD5guBm+H3vi1wwJNgtOjrZEGiFjAgofJFlWQO5UUn4YfM=, api error PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.with aws_s3_bucket_policy.sankethcl1234_us_west_1[1],
> on main.tf line 77, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1":
> 77: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1" {

> Error: putting S3 Bucket (sankethcl1234-us-west-1-1) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 301, RequestID: G4BC4QJP0YQ6NPHS, HostID: HSHXHl4p3Has2DEC0GoQpzecRjMdUhd//9FpdFiyq1oT+FnOEeyvIvKXcg8GJlTj2TsDG781tEM=, api error PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.with aws_s3_bucket_policy.sankethcl1234_us_west_1[0],
> on main.tf line 77, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1":
> 77: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1" {

I tried creating s3 buckets but policies in json not able to upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each resource, including bucket policies, has to use the same provider configuration in order to be attached to the corresponding bucket. Otherwise, terraform will try to attach them to the bucket which is using the non-aliased provider (i.e., `provider "aws"`). In other words:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1" {
  count    = 2
  provider = aws.us-east-1
  bucket   = "${var.bucket_prefix}-us-east-1-${count.index + 1}"
  acl      = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_east_1" {
  provider = aws.us-east-1
  count    = 2
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_east_1[count.index].id
  policy   = templatefile("${path.module}/bucket_policy_east.json", { 
    bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_east_1[count.index].id 
  })
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1" {
  provider = aws.us-west-1
  count    = 2
  bucket   = "${var.bucket_prefix}-us-west-1-${count.index + 1}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "sankethcl1234_us_west_1" {
  provider = aws.us-west-1
  count    = 2
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_west_1[count.index].id
  policy   = templatefile("${path.module}/bucket_policy_west.json", { 
    bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.sankethcl1234_us_west_1[count.index].id
  })
}
```

You would then do the same for all the regions you want to have buckets and bucket policies in.

Comment: it worked thank you for help.

Comment: Please make sure you read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow/86979#86979.